# OTC-Editor displays an error dialog on click of "Show Tree" button for certain types

Tags: otcconverter, otcframework

OTC-Editor displays an error dialog on click of "Show Tree" button for certain types.[image]
Please find the attached screenshot.
Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Would require more info - please provide the jars containing both the types to reproduce.

Please create an issue on github https://github.com/frank-a-otc/otcframework/issues  and upload the files.  Will check and revert.